Looking for the title of a movie where people can live in a body of another human
I'm looking for the title of a movie where the synopsis is a world where people can rent their bodies to other people.
Generally, rich people can pay and transfer their soul in another body to live fantasies by connecting themselves on a machine. I remember that in the story, somebody scrap a girl body by taking drugs, going to club and painting their hair, tattoos, etc. (It's not a principal character).
I think this film was released around 2006-2010.
It's similar to the movie "Gamer" (2009) and "Transfer" (2010).

We've had a very similar question recently. Is this what you're after?

Wow, the story is almost identical, but it's not this movie. I will add new details to my question.

Oh god!
The movie I was looking for was inside my question. 
Yeah, the answer is Gamer!
I found it because of this clip and this clip.
I didn't know it was this movie because all trailer show battles, armies and action but theses clips is exactly a part of what I was searching for. 

You can mark your own answer as 'accepted', so we all know the question has been answered ;)
